# How to list out Virtual Directories in IIS from the all the websites in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012, iis-8, virtual-directory

I have hit a complete roadblock and cannot figure out how to print out the virtual directories for each website in `IIS 8`. I keep retrieving Applications and empty null argument errors and just can't find a way around to get the virtual directories to list out.

I need the following data to list out about the Virtual Directories:

- Physical Path
- App Pool Association
- Site Name
- Credentials

Below is the code I have been using and messing around with:

```
    *See revised code below*
```

I have also used the `Appcmd.exe` command to try and to list out the Virtual Directories:

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe LIST VDIRS
```

But I am still not getting the output I need. Anything or any help would be highly appreciated! Thanks!

## EDIT#----------------------------------------------------------------------

Got my virtual directories to list out by commenting out a couple lines but it only prints out the name and the:

- Physical Path
- App Pool Association
- Site Name
- Credentials

are still unknown to me, below is the revised code:

```
  Import-Module WebAdministration
    $Websites = Get-ChildItem IIS:\Sites 
    foreach($Site in $Websites)
            {
                $webapps = Get-WebApplication -Site $Site.name 
                $VDir = Get-WebVirtualDirectory -Site $Site.name #-Application $webapps.name
                                foreach($webvdirectory in $VDir)
                                    {
                                        $webvdirectory2 = $webvdirectory.path
                                        Write-Host $webvdirectory2.split("/")[-1]
                                        #Write-Host $webvdirectory
                                        #Write-Host $webvdirectory.name
                           
                                    } 
                            #Write-Host $VDir 
            
            }
```

Comment: Unless you convert a virtual directory to an application, it inherits the site's application pool.  Are you also looking for virtual directories which are converted to applications as well as "normal" virtual directories?

Comment: $jscott I am looking to print out **all** virtual directories that exist in IIS, and the specified information I listed at the top.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You write that you can't figure out how to retrieve:

- Physical Path

  - is directly accessible through the `physicalPath` noteproperty
- App Pool Association

  - doesn't make sense, *Applications* are assigned to app pools, directories themselves are not
- Site Name

  - You already know this (`$Site.name`)
- Credentials

  - I assume you just want the username if present

These could all be retrieved with some slight alterations to your existing script:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration

$Websites = Get-ChildItem IIS:\Sites 

$AllVDirs = @()

foreach($Site in $Websites)
{
    $VDirs = Get-WebVirtualDirectory -Site $Site.name
    foreach($webvdirectory in $VDirs)
    {
            $vdir = New-Object psobject -Property @{
                "Name" = ($webvdirectory.path -split "/")[-1]
                "Site" = $Site.name
                "Path" = $webvdirectory.path
                "PhysicalPath" = $webvdirectory.physicalPath
                "PhysicalPathCredentials" = $webvdirectory.userName
            }

            $AllVDirs += $vdir
    } 
}

$AllVDirs
```

Now you can export `$AllVDirs` to Xml, Csv or simply print it to the PowerShell host.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you @Mathias R. Jessen , I forgot about this post and I should've came back because I figured most of it out. Your script works perfect and here's mine just for S&Gs, didn't realize all I had to do was call on the objects and properties.

```
$Websites = Get-ChildItem IIS:\Sites 
    foreach($Site in $Websites)
            {
                $webapps = Get-WebApplication -Site $Site.name 
                $VDir = Get-WebVirtualDirectory -Site $Site.name #-Application $webapps.name
                                foreach($webvdirectory in $VDir)
                                    {
                                        $webvdirectory2 = $webvdirectory.path
                                        Write-Host $webvdirectory2.split("/")[-1] "::: is the Virtual Directory" -ForegroundColor Green
                                        Write-Host $webvdirectory.physicalPath   
                                        Write-Host $webvdirectory.userName                                         
                                        Write-Host $webvdirectory.password
                                        Write-Host $webvdirectory.logonMethod
                                    } 
                            #Write-Host $VDir 

            }
```

Also have another problem though and didn't know if you had the answer, how would I call on the Physical Path credentials property for web applications? I cant print out the username or password, but I can print the logonMethod which uses the same property? below is my code for web applications, it is very similar to my virtual directories code:

```
$Websites = Get-ChildItem IIS:\Sites 
    foreach($Site in $Websites)
            { 
             $webapps = Get-WebApplication -Site $Site.name 
                    foreach($webapp in $webAPPS)
                        {
                        Write-Host $webapp.applicationPool
                        Write-Host $WebApp.virtualDirectoryDefaults.userName
                        Write-Host $webapp.virtualDirectoryDefaults.password
                        Write-Host $webapp.virtualDirectoryDefaults.logonMethod
                        $webapp2 = $webapp.path
                        Write-Host $WebApp2.split("/")[-1] "::: is the Web Application" -ForegroundColor Green

                        } 
            }
```

Comment: I am also thinking if I get the $Site.userName and the $Site.password, wouldn't they be the same for the Web App?

Answer (score 1):

This will create an array that contains the Site Name, Virtual Directory Name and Virtual Directory Physical Path.

```
$SiteVirtualDirectories = @()
$Sites = gci IIS:\Sites
foreach($Site in $Sites)
    {
    $VirtualDirectories = gci "IIS:\Sites\$($Site.Name)" | ?{$_.NodeType -match "virtualDirectory"}
    foreach($VirtualDirectory in $VirtualDirectories)
        {
        $SiteVirtualDirectories += @([pscustomobject]@{Site=$Site.Name;VirtualDirectory=$VirtualDirectory.Name;PhysicalPath=$VirtualDirectory.PhysicalPath})
        }
    }
Write-Host $SiteVirtualDirectories
```